# Wrong width of an absolute positioned list element with limited height and vertical scrollbar in Firefox

Tags: css

I have an absolute positioned menu element with limited height. Thus the vertical scrollbar should appear. Below is an simplified version of my code.

Running it on Windows 10 in Edge, Chrome 63, IE11 it looks just fine. That means text is visible, padding is left and right.

However in Firefox 57.0.4, the text is slightly cut from the right side. It seems to me as if Firefox, unlike other browsers, doesn't reserve space for the scrollbar.

Is there a way how to fix it?

```css
ul, li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid black;
  list-style: none;
  max-height: 120px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

li {
  padding: 5px 15px;
}

span {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><span>test text</span></li>
  <li><span>test text</span></li>
  <li><span>test text</span></li>
  <li><span>test text</span></li>
  <li><span>test text</span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: try using `overflow-y: scroll;` instead of `hidden`, `auto` behavior can differ between browsers

Answer (score 0):

try it with `overflow-y:scroll;` instead of `auto`, some browsers don't interpret auto in the same way as others.

Comment: It works, but when there are just few list items, an empty scrollbar is visible. I don't want to show scrollbar when it's not necessary.

Comment: you can use auto and `padding-right:18px;` if you want it to be automatic